# lcov remove option is not removing coverage data as expected

Tags: code-coverage, lcov

I'm using lcov to generate coverage reports. I have a tracefile (`broker.info`) with this content (relevant fragment shown):

```
$ lcov -r broker.info
...
[/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ContextBroker-PreBuild-UnitTest/workspace/test/unittests/orionTypes/]
EntityTypeResponse_test.cpp                    | 100%    11| 100%   6|    -    0
...

[/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ContextBroker-PreBuild-UnitTest/workspace/test/unittests/parse/]
CompoundValueNode_test.cpp                     | 100%    82| 100%  18|    -    0
...

[/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ContextBroker-PreBuild-UnitTest/workspace/test/unittests/rest/]
OrionError_test.cpp                            |92.1%    38| 100%   6|    -    0
...

[/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ContextBroker-PreBuild-UnitTest/workspace/test/unittests/serviceRoutines/]
badVerbAllFour_test.cpp                        | 100%    24| 100%   7|    -    0
...
```

I want to remove all the info corresponding to `test/unittest` files.

I have attemped to use the `-r` option which, according to man page is:

> -r tracefile pattern
>     --remove tracefile pattern
>            Remove data from tracefile.
>
> Use this switch if you want to remove coverage data for a particular set of files from a tracefile. Additional command line parameters will be interpreted as
>     shell  wildcard  patterns  (note that they may need to be escaped accordingly to prevent the shell from expanding them first).  Every file entry in tracefile
>     which matches at least one of those patterns will be removed.
>
> The result of the remove operation will be written to stdout or the tracefile specified with -o.
>
> Only one of  -z, -c, -a, -e, -r, -l, --diff or --summary may be specified at a time.

Thus, I'm using

```
$ lcov -r broker.info 'test/unittests/*' -o broker.info2
```

As far as I understand `test/unittest/*` matches the files under `test/unittest`. However, it's not working (note `Deleted 0 files` below):

```
Reading tracefile broker.info
Deleted 0 files
Writing data to broker.info2
Summary coverage rate:
  lines......: 92.6% (58313 of 62978 lines)
  functions..: 96.0% (6451 of 6718 functions)
  branches...: no data found
```

I have tried also this variants (same result):

```
$ lcov -r broker.info "test/unittests/*" -o broker.info2
$ lcov -r broker.info "test/unittests/\*" -o broker.info2
$ lcov -r broker.info "test/unittests" -o broker.info2
```

So, maybe I'm doing something wrong?

I'm using lcov version 1.13 (just in case the data is relevant)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have been testing another options and the following one seems to work, using the wildcard in the prefix also:

```
$ lcov -r broker.info "*/test/unittests/*" -o broker.info2
```

Maybe it is something new in version 1.13 because in version 1.11 it seems it works without wildcard in the prefix...

Answer (score 1):

The below mentioned lcov command is working fine, even with wild characters (lcov 1.14):

```
lcov --remove meson-logs/coverage.info '/home/builduser/external/*' '/home/builduser/unittest/*' -o meson-logs/sourcecoverage.info
```

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is using wildcards in a rooted path [as described in their docs](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Lcov)

```
lcov --remove coverage.info "/usr/*" "/*/unit_tests/*" "/*/thirdparty/*" --output-file coverage.info
```